# Module(s) doesn't enable properly with Drush

Tags: drush, installation

I have installed Acquia's DevDesktop 2 to create local sites and while testing D8.3.6 I have found an interesting issue. When I enable various modules with drush (drush en paragraphs (example)) drush reports the module installed correctly however when I try to use the module the site errors. The way to fix this is to uninstall with drush then use the Drupal UI to enable the module and all is fine.

The version of drush shipped with the latest version of DevDesktop is 8.1.10

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in either Drush, Drupal or the Entity Reference Revisions module (which the Paragraphs module depends on). The solution is to enable the Entity Reference Revisions or the Paragraphs module from Drupal itself, not with Drush. You can safely download the modules with Drush.

See my Drush issue at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2873 for more information.

No, I can't reproduce this issue with other modules. (I'm using the same setup as you.)